# Where is the SASS version of all styles for Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap makes a great deal of how they fully switch to SASS from version 4. However, when I browsed my *node_modules*, I realized that everything there is still in SCSS.

I know that the difference isn't that big but I do like the absence of curlies and I'd prefer to see SASS-like SASS-ing.

Where can I find the ortodox SASS source code? Or am I missing something profound and am simply reasoning mistakenly?

Comment: SCSS is *SASS*, it's the current primary syntax of [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) vs the indented style (.sass). You can easily still use the indented style if that's what you prefer since all you should be doing is importing Bootstrap into your project. Any Bootstrap variables you want to change can still be written with the indented style, just use your own variables file before you import Bootstrap and you should be golden.

Comment: @sidbiffi How come you deleted the answer? I had a comment to it. It seems that you linked to a general repository. Where are the SASS files?

Comment: Actually it looks like a moderator removed the answer but heres the link that was posted [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem). Again, this isn't the indented syntax (*.sass*) it's SCSS.

Comment: @vanburen My intention is to use Gulp to transpile SASS of Bootstrap and the custom SASS of ours. Then, I'd like to pack it into a single file (or a small number of files as I saw that Booty offers four separate *.min.css* files). I also am going to try to use Gulp to pack the JS into a single *bundle.js* file. But the impression I'm getting from your comment is that I should let the pre-transpiled files be as they are and just add my own to the set. Is that correct?

Comment: @vanburen You also mentioned **importing** while I simply use a tag in *index.html* to point them out. Is it possible to *import Booty from *bootstrap*? That's a new one. I'd be delighted if it was doable, in fact.

Comment: If you're going to use a preprocessor like SASS then you may as well take advantage of it and only import the files your need from Bootstrap or wherever (instead of every single component unless you need them all) and concatenate them into a single file for production just like you plan on doing with your javascript. Here's an image to give you a very basic idea of the file structure: https://imgur.com/a/4Z5rS.

Comment: @vanburen Please feel free to post it as a reply so it can get accepted.